# How do I stop an Azure Container Instance?

Tags: azure, docker, command

I'm still new to the Azure Container Instance scene. I have managed to complete the container instance tutorial. However, I've noticed that the tutorial does not show the reader how to stop a running container instance. The nearest command that gaurantees the container instance is indeed stopped / terminated, is by deleting the Resource Group which created the container.

`az group delete -n <ResourceGroupNameThatCreatedContainerInstance>`

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [az container delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-delete)

```
az container delete -g MyResourceGroup --name mynginx
```

Answer (score 3):

The Azure CLI updated and now its [possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-stop).

Stop

```sh
az container stop --name
                  --resource-group
                  [--subscription]
```

Restart

```sh
az container restart --name
                     --resource-group
                     [--subscription]
```